# Use Generic Type for ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, generics, resttemplate

I have a Generic method `callOutOfBoundServices` that calls external services

```
public <T> T callOutOfBoundServices(String... args) {
        return resultofOutsideServices(args).getBody();
    }

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> resultofOutsideServices(String... args) {
            // Business Logic. Building restTemplate call
        }
```

The above method works for plain POJOs, but I have a unique use-case where I have to use it for **ResponseEntity**. Is it possible to call the method in a generic way for **ResponseEntity** without changing the method signature?

I tried this call:

```
ResponseEntity<EmployeePOJO> rs = callOutOfBoundServices(args);
```

but I am getting:

```
Incompatible types: Required ResponseEntity<EmployeePOJO> but type was inferred to T for callOutOfBoundServices.
```

Note:

1. Using Spring Boot application where current and outside services are also Spring-based applications.
2. Using Spring's RestTemplate to all outside services.

Comment: what is the signature of the `resultofOutsideServices(args)` method?

Answer (score 1):

As you return EmployeePojo object you didn't need to write **T** over there

```
public ResponseEntity<EmployeePojo> callOutOfBoundServices(String... args) {
        return resultofOutsideServices(args);
    }
```

You must have to return an EmployeePojo object

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(employeePojoObj);
```

Comment: As I have stated in my question, I do not want to change method signature for callOutOfBoundServices

Comment: Can you give more detail of your method `callOutOfBoundServices(String... args)` 
and its return type `resultofOutsideServices(args)` it would be very helpful to solve your problem

Comment: resultofOutsideServices is a wrapper around resttemplate. Its details are abstracted away.